# How can you get future-dated posts in Django?

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I just want to do a basic site in Django and the flatpages app is super simple, but it doesn't support a couple of things that I need, namely custom fields and future-dating. That is setting a publish date to some point in the future rather than publishing immediately.

What's the best option for getting future-dated posts in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is the same as your question "Is there anything better than Flatpages?"

**[django-cms](http://django-cms.org/)** allows you to arrange your flatpages in a hierarchical structure and lets you set a future publish date.

By custom fields I assume you mean fields defined by users?  If so then you'll have to implement that yourself on top of django-cms.